# Python lists and their splitting

Tags: python, list

For example, I have such code

```
a = ["a;b", "c;d",...,"y;z"]
```

I want to split every list element into to items of the same list. So i wanna get something like this:

```
["a", "b", "c", "d", ...., "y", "z"]
```

How can I do such thing? Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using only string operations seem to be *simplest* (this is subjective, of course) and **fastest** (by a huge margin, compared to other solutions posted so far).

```
>>> a = ["a;b", "c;d", "y;z"]
>>> ";".join(a).split(";")
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'y', 'z']
```

#### Proof / benchmarks

Sorted in ascending order of elapsed time:

```
python -mtimeit -s'a=["a;b","x;y","p;q"]*99' '";".join(a).split(";")'
10000 loops, best of 3: 48.2 usec per loop

python -mtimeit -s'a=["a;b","x;y","p;q"]*99' '[single for pair in a for single in pair.split(";")]'
1000 loops, best of 3: 347 usec per loop

python -mtimeit -s'from itertools import chain; a=["a;b","x;y","p;q"]*99' 'list(chain(*(s.split(";") for s in a)))'
1000 loops, best of 3: 350 usec per loop

python -mtimeit -s'a=["a;b","x;y","p;q"]*99' 'sum([x.split(";") for x in a],[])'
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.13 msec per loop

python -mtimeit -s'a=["a;b","x;y","p;q"]*99' 'sum(map(lambda x: x.split(";"), a), [])'
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.22 msec per loop

python -mtimeit -s'a=["a;b","x;y","p;q"]*99' 'reduce(lambda x,y:x+y, [pair.split(";") for pair in a])'
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.24 msec per loop
```

Comment: "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."  Oh, well.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
>>> a = ["a;b", "c;d","y;z"]
>>> list(itertools.chain(*(s.split(';') for s in a)))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'y', 'z']
```

Comment: Great! One-line solution) itertools but so elegant!

Answer (score 3):

A bit more functional approach:

```
>>> l = ["a;b", "c;d", "e;f", "y;z"]
>>> sum(map(lambda x: x.split(';'), l), [])
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'y', 'z']
```

Comment: Using `sum` for flattening a list is... well, not evil but pretty counter-intuitive.

Comment: I think it's just a matter of taste. It's definitely more readable than `[ y for z in [ x.split(';') for x in a ] for y in z ]`, which is the most performant solution, btw.

Comment: I thought it was fairly intuitive and readable; I could see having done it this way.

Comment: @delnan: Why? The desired output list *is* exactly `[] + ['a', 'b'] + ['c', 'd'] + ['e', 'f'] + ['y', 'z']`, thus it *is* a sum of those lists (which is what the code does).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: No, it's not the *sum*. Summing is commutative, for starters. It's those lists concatenated, which is a distinct operation although the operator for concatenation happens to be used for summation as well.

Answer (score 1):

That's work :

```
l = []
for item in ["a;b", "c;d", "e;f"]:
     l += item.split(";")

print l
```

It gives :

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ["a;b", "c;d","y;z"]
print [atom for pair in a for atom in pair.split(';')]
```

gives what you want:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'y', 'z']
```

note: i  can't tell you how to get from '...' to '....' in the middle of your array :)

Comment: +1: There is indeed no need for itertools, for such a simple case.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = []
for current in [c.split(';') for c in a]:
   l.extend(current)
```

You might want to read up on list comprehensions http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ["a;b", "c;d","e;f","y;z"]
b = []
for i in a:
    c = i.split(';')
    b = b + c

print b
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit longer than Felix Kling's answer, but here goes. First split the list into sub-lists

```
>>> a_split = [i.split(";", 1) for i in a]
```

This will result in a list of the form:

```
[[a,b], [c,d], ..., [y,z]]
```

You now need to 'merge' the inner and outer lists in some way. The builtin `reduce()` function is a perfect fit for this:

```
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, a_split)
```

Voila:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', ... 'y', 'z']
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings can be used for this:

```
>>> a = ["a;b", "c;d","y;z"]
>>> list(''.join(a).replace(';', ''))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'y', 'z']
```

This solution is one of the fastest suggested so far:

```
# Shawn Chin's solution (the fastest so far, by far):
python -mtimeit -s'a=["a;b","x;y","p;q"]*99' '";".join(a).split(";")'
10000 loops, best of 3: 27.4 usec per loop

# This solution:
python -mtimeit -s'a=["a;b","x;y","p;q"]*99' "list(''.join(a).replace(';', ''))"
10000 loops, best of 3: 33.5 usec per loop
```

The morale is that lists represented by strings can be quite efficient in this case, possibly because of a simpler memory handling (characters are stored in consecutive memory locations).